# (How) Does temperature affect the light absorption of molecular systems?

Tags: visible-light, temperature, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, absorption

My concern is color reflectance spectra that show slightly different characteristics under different sample temperatures.  I am trying to find out the reason for this and would like to understand what influence the temperature has on the absorption properties of substances, generally.

#### Starting point

When I heat different inks containing organic colorants (e.g. from 20 to 50 °C using an PTC heating element), I can observe several effects in spectral reflectance with increasing temperature. Most inks show an increasing red shift and decreasing reflectance which is reversible when the sample cools down.

Temperature-dependent changes in spectral absorption is a known phenomenon of colored objects and can also be observed for transmitting glass filter, for example.

The absorption of colorants is mainly caused by $\mu-\mu^\star$ electron transitions of conjugated and delocalized C=C double bonds with corresponding energy in visible range of the electromagnetic spectrum.

#### Assumption

Gathering all my poor knowledge about physics, I would assume that the energy induced by heating the sample leads to a stronger vibration of the molecules. Due to this vibration the necessary excitation energy for $\mu-\mu^\star$ electron transition decreases what shifts the absorption spectrum towards longer and less energized wavelengths – at least this is my assumption.
Another thought that comes to my mind is that the delocalization of the bonds increases due to the vibrational states (why ever it should do that) and thus the absorption shifts.

#### Question

Is it physically plausible that a higher sample temperature decreases the necessary energy amount for electron transitions? What other influences does an increase in temperature have on the absorption properties of molecular systems/colorants? Does any of my assumptions make sense?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about Mossbauer spectroscopy    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_spectroscopy#M%C3%B6ssbauer_emission_spectroscopy  as that's close to what you are proposing here.    However,  my guess is that ink, being a mixture of **lots of stuff** and quite possibly containing undissolved particulates, may separate out upon heating and that's the primary cause of the color-change you're observing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks, I have read about Mössbauer spectroscopy, but honestly I don't understand the reference.  
In my opinion, the fact that the effects are reversible when the sample cools down speaks against a separation of the ink components or any significant change in ink condition.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are observing the visible light spectral (photon energy 2 - 4 eV), the absorption are mainly from the transition of electron between the occupied state and the empty state. Vibration only gives to one of the factors determine the linewidth.

The spacing of energy levels are determined by the interation strength between the contituent molecues. Greater inter-molecular interaction leads to a wider splitting oof the energy level. The strength of interaction is a function of inter-molecular distance.

As temperature increase, the inter-molecular distance becomes larger, and the interation between molecules becomes weaker. Thus, higher temperature is weakening the inter-molecular interaction, and narrowing the spacing of energy levels. This leads to a red-shift of the spectral.

For example, the band gap of semiconductor is always becoming smaller with increasing temperature. In the case of GaAs, the band gap is 1.44 eV at room temperature, droped from 1.52 eV at low temperature.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have already read about the temperature-dependent band gap of semiconductors, but was unsure if this mechanism also applies to non-semiconductors. If I understand your explanation correctly, all electron excitation processes are more ore less temperature dependent.

Comment: Yes. Because thermal exapnsion enlarge the spacing between the constituent elements, and change the energy levels.

Comment: I have to rehash this topic again, because some things are still unclear for me. 
You write that the vibrations influence the line width - so far so clear. But do the different vibronic states also could have direct influence the electron excitation resp. the energy gap between occupied and empty state? Or only indirectly through thermal expansion? 
My question aims to know if thermal expansion is the only/prevailing factor influencing the spectral shift.